# Solving for 4 variables using only 2 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, diophantine-equations, factoring, integers

Given $ab (c + d)+(a + b) cd = 2018$ and 
$(ab + 1) (cd + 1) + (a + b-
1) (c + d-
1) = -1$ and $a,b,c,d$ are integers, find all solution tuples.

So I have tried to factorize this and get $(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)=-2020$ by subtracting second equation from the first; but now I have no idea how to continue. Do I just try all the possible sets of $a,b,c,d$? I think it is a possible way but there are $1280$ possible tuples of $a,b,c,d$; it is just to much to compute. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this a future version of the question you asked in combinatorics tag.  So this was the real problem right?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was changed. In the original problem was the following given.

$$(ab + 1) (cd + 1) + (a + b-
1) (c + d-
1) = 1$$

It should be $$(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)=-2018$$ and since $$2018=2\cdot1009,$$ where $1009$ is prime, we have not so many cases.